# Need help scraping image from craigslist

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, web-scraping, cheerio

I've tried everything I can think of. I'm able to get postUrl, date, title, price and location. If you go to https://sandiego.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=surfboards and paste the code snippet below into the console it returns all the images. But when I try to access in my code it's returning undefined. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
$('#search-results > li').each((index, element) => {
   console.log( $(element).children().find('img').attr('src') )
})
```

```
import axios from 'axios'
import request from 'request-promise'
import cheerio from 'cheerio'
import express from 'express'

import path from 'path'
const __dirname = path.resolve();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();

app.get('', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
});

const surfboards = [];

axios("https://sandiego.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=surfboards")
.then(res => {
  const htmlData = res.data;
  const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);

  $('#search-results > li').each((index, element) => {
    const postUrl = $(element).children('a').attr('href');
    const date = $(element).children('.result-info').children('.result-date').text();
    const title = $(element).children('.result-info').children('.result-heading').text().trim();
    const price = $(element).children('.result-info').children('.result-meta').children('.result-price').text();
    const location = $(element).children('.result-info').children('.result-meta').children(".result-hood").text().trim();

  
    // Why is this not working?!?!?!?!?!
    const img = $(element).children().find('img').attr('src');
    
    surfboards.push({
      title,
      postUrl,
      date,
      price,
      location,
      img
    })
  })
  return surfboards
}).catch(err => console.error(err))

app.get('/api/surfboards', (req, res) => {

  const usedboards = surfboards
  
  return res.status(200).json({
    results: usedboards
  })
})
// Make App listen
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening to port ${PORT}`))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the page sets the images with JavaScript. Thus `axios` gets the HTML without actual links to images.

But there seems to be a workaround here. You can generate links to images by concatenate https://images.craigslist.org and `data-ids` value from parent `a` tag.

[image]

You can get the `data-ids` like this:

```
var data_ids = $(element).children('a').attr('data-ids')
```

then split it to array by comma, delete first two `3:` symbols and concat it like this:

```
`${img_base_url}/${ids}_${resolution_and_extension}`
```

But if you need to get URL only for first image then there is no need to create new array each time. Use substring instead (note that sometimes `li` don't have image at all):

```
if (data_ids && data_ids.includes(',')) {
    data_ids.substring(data_ids.indexOf('3:') + 2, data_ids.indexOf(','))
} else if (data_ids) {
    data_ids.substring(data_ids.indexOf('3:') + 2, data_ids.length)
}
```